# Cash flow diagram displaying interest rates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I could use some help with drawing a cash flow diagram that displays the interest rates using LaTex. Something like this:
[image]

I've been struggling to draw the cash flow diagram using the tikz-pgf package. Any form of help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Wfae you try so far? where you stuck in your efforts solve your problem yoursel?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe someone will answer your question as is, but usually we expect that you show what you've got so far and tell us where you got stuck. Use the edit button at the bottom left of your posting to add the LaTeX code (stripped down to the essential parts). In the post editor, select the code and press the button marked `{}`, in order to display the code adequately.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{sansmath} 
\usepackage{pst-plot, pst-arrow, pst-node}

\begin{document}

\sffamily\sansmath
\begin{pspicture}(0,-2)(5,4)
\psset{unit = 1.5cm, ticksize=-4pt 0, linejoin=1, dotstyle=|, tbarsize=6pt 2}
\psaxes[yAxis=false]{-}(0,0)(3,0)
\psline{-v}(1,0)(1,2)\uput[u](1,2){200}
\psline{-v}(3,0)(3,1)\uput[u](3,1){100}
\psaxes[yAxis=false, xAxis = false, ticksize=-6pt 2pt]{-}(0,-1)(3,-1)
\pnodes{A}(0,-0.8)(2,-0.8) (3,-0.8)
\ncline{|<->|}{A0}{A1}\nbput{$ \mathrm{i}=12\% $}
\ncline{<->|}{A1}{A2}\nbput{$ \mathsf{i}=7\% $}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.